# Delete all punctuation symbols exept underscore and curly braces in string in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-negation

Suppose I have a string

```
s = "Hey, {customer_name}, what's up?"
```

What is the appropriate regular expression to remove all punctuation symbols except underscore and curly braces?

Comment: `[^A-Za-z0-9 _{}]+`? Demo: https://regex101.com/r/NmQouR/1. Or a shorter version: `[^\w{} ]+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` with pattern `[^\w _{}]` which will ignore all alphanumberic characters, but will include underscore `_` and curly braces `{}`

```
import re

s = "Hey, {customer_name}, what's up?"
print(re.sub(r'[^\w {}]','',s))
```

Output is `Hey {customer_name} whats up`

Comment: You are right, fixed! Thanks @AhmedAbdelhameed :) Please check if it looks good and consider upvoting if it is :)